# How do I pick things up off the floor?

Tags: felspire

Can someone tell me how I can pick things up?

Comment: Hi, I've edited your question to try to make it clearer.  If that's not what you intended to ask, feel free to rollback from [the revision history](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/238392/revisions) or ping me by starting a comment here with "@John"

Answer (score 1):

You either

1. Click the item you want to pick up,
2. Use the space bar while close to the item or
3. Use one of the companions that pick items up for you - Bobbie or Panda